# take out value of li jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have given

```
<ul class="test1" style="height: 175px;">
    <li class=" ">
        <label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-0">
            <input type="checkbox" aria-selected="true" title="" value="All" name="multiselect_apps_data_usage_operator_country" id="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-0"><span>All</span>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li class=" ">
        <label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-1">
            <input type="checkbox" title="" value="1" name="multiselect_apps_data_usage_operator_country" id="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-1" aria-selected="true"><span>XYZ</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to take out that value of span from li where input aria-selected="true" through jquery. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
        if ( $(this).attr('aria-selected') == 'true' ){
            alert($(this).next().text())

        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/2b8bzpqr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('li input[aria-selected="true"] + span').text();
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  alert($('li input[aria-selected="true"] + span').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test1" style="height: 175px;">
  <li class=" ">
    <label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-0">
      <input type="checkbox" aria-selected="true" title="" value="All" name="multiselect_apps_data_usage_operator_country" id="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-0"><span>All</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label class="ui-corner-all" title="" for="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-1">
      <input type="checkbox" title="" value="1" name="multiselect_apps_data_usage_operator_country" id="ui-multiselect-apps_data_usage_operator_country-option-1" aria-selected="true"><span>XYZ</span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner might do it.

```
alert($(":checkbox[aria-selected='true'] + span").text());
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/c04Lb989/8/)